# Re-render/refresh same view after ajax call

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo, controller, action

I just want to ask if it is possible to re-render the same view through dojo xhrpost?

On my /app/index.phtml page I have a button that will fire an action through dojo xhrpost which will call the same /app action controller.

It successfully calls the controller but the page is not rendering with the updated data.

Here's the ajax call part

```
  var xhrArgs = {
            url: "/app",
            handleAs: "text",
            load: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
    }
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

Controller

```
      public function indexAction()
{
    $apps = new Application_Model_Application();
    if($this->_request->isPost()){
          $this->view->apps = $apps->getAppsById("2");
    }else{
          $this->view->apps = $apps->getAllApps();
    }
    $this->render();
 }
```

I'm getting the response on firebug which gives me the rendered page but the actual view itself is not re-loaded with the new apps data ($this->view->apps)

Am I missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Dojo to render the new retrieved data into the DOM of your page. The controller will return it into the variable, but won't display it.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to  re-render the page through ajax when calling the same action on that view? if I call a differnt action like /app/dosomething the dosomething.phtml gets rendered so I'm thinking that it is possible through ajax since I need the updated data set by the controller which will be utilized by my view helper on reload..please enlighten me as I'm new to zend..thanks